# npm run dev error involving webpack and babel following online course

Tags: javascript, webpack, command-line

I am taking the complete javaScript course by Jonas Schmedtmann on Udemy. I just barely got to the first use of the command line and since the course from recording is a little outdated he has links to download Webpack and Babel just to follow the course smoothly as he does it on video.

I download the links but when I use "npm run dev" on the command line I get an error instead of the same results I've watched the course video multiple times to make sure I follow everything he does and I cannot figure out why. I have also posted on Udemy's Q&A for the last 4 days with no responses. I need help fixing this before I can continue the course. Here is the screenshots of the code and of the command line errors. link to the command line error below.

Comment: At least I thought there was a link to the picture since you cant embed pictures to posts. StackOverflow said there was one when I posted the question.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: !https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLswT.jpg I figured out how to post the picture